# How reslove pointer to array from pointer to single object

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

I try in my porogram find way to resolve beetwen type pointer to array form pointer to single object using `interface{}` as argument in particular function. On this time i get this reslut using below way:

```
func object( v interface{}) {
    if strings.HasPrefix(reflect.TypeOf(v).String(), "*[]") {
        // pointer to array 
    } else {
        //  pointer to single object
    }
}
```

Above way works, but for me this is not clean code. I think that exist some better way to solve this using golang package as type, reflect but now I don't no how so please Your suggestion.

Ps. I don't want to use `switch` statemet for example:

```
switch v.(type){
case *[]someType:
  // array
default:
  // single object
}
```

This should be more universal does not depend on the type object of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`reflect.Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) to check the kind of value you have:

```
func object(i interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        fmt.Print("we have a pointer ")
        switch v.Elem().Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            fmt.Println("to a slice")
        case reflect.Array:
            fmt.Println("to an array")
        case reflect.Struct:
            fmt.Println("to a struct")
        default:
            fmt.Println("to unexpected type ", v.Elem().Kind())
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/q32Cfz_dmF